# Projective modules restricted to smooth curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, projective-modules

I asked this question on [Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032940/projective-modules-restricted-to-smooth-curves), but no one answered this.

I want to prove a coherent sheaf $M$ on $X$ is locally free if and only if this is true for $M|_{X'}$ ,
for all smooth curves $X'$ mapping to $X$. I think the only if direction is obvious. For the if direction, a coherent module is flat if and only if it is projective, for Dedekind domains if and only if torsion free as well. So I am thinking of using Tor$_1$. There is [local criterion for flatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_criterion_for_flatness), but I am not sure if this will help.

This is used at the beginning of the proof of Proposition 5.13 of [Gaitsgory's lecture notes](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/267y/catO.pdf).

Comment: Try EGA IV Vol. 3, Thm. 11.8.1 ("valuative criterion of flatness").

Comment: @Piotr Achinger: I don't see how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: @abx Of course your answer is much simpler. But the reference (applied with $X=Y$ reduced noetherian) says that we can check flatness of a coherent sheaf by restricting to spectra of dvr's mapping to $X$. (Still, one needs to check that it is enough to consider dvrs coming from maps from curves, so you do have a point.)

Comment: @ Piotr Achinger: I agree. I was confused about what "$f$-flat" means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that $X$ is integral and smooth (as in Gaitsgory's notes). For any two points $x,y$ in $X$, there is a smooth connected curve $C$ passing through $x$ and $y$. Since $M_{|C}$ is locally free, this implies $\dim M_x/\mathfrak{m}_xM_x=\dim M_y/\mathfrak{m}_yM_y$, where  $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$. But this implies that $M$ is locally free.

Answer (score 0):

In Borel's book "Algebraic D-modules" the the following result is proved:

**Propositon VI.1.7** If $M$ is a $D_X$-module that is coherent as $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then $M$ is locally free.

**Question.** "This is used at the beginning of the proof of Proposition 5.13 of Gaitsgory's lecture notes."

**Answer:** If you are interested in an alternative proof  of the proof of Gaitsgory's Proposition 5.13 you do not need the connection to be flat for the result to hold. Hence if $X$ is a regular scheme of finite type over a field $k$ of characteristic zero and if $M$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module with a connection

$$\nabla: M\rightarrow M\otimes \Omega^1 $$

then $M$ is locally free. The proof is given in the book and does not use curves.

Comment: Any relation with the question???